# HTML5 Global variable different in two places

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

so i'm working on the basics of a platformer in HTML5, and since I'm just learning it, I'm having a few problems. I have a way to jump, but sometimes the object will fall below the "ground" even though I have an if statement that is executed every tick to see if the object is below the ground and if it is place it back up.

Here is the "game": http://www.freeminecrafthost.com/RealWorld/JDev/

I went into the chrome debugger and when I got the player under the "ground" I paused the execution and y was equal to 440 in the player function. but in the paint function it wasn't

Any ideas?

The code in question is:

```
this.move = function(){
        if(this.isJumping){
            this.y -= jumprate;
            jumprate--;
        }
        if (this.y>440){
            this.isJumping = false;
            y = 440;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please show the relevant code in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
if (this.y>440){
   this.isJumping = false;
   y = 440;
}
```

Should be

```
if (this.y>440){
   this.isJumping = false;
   this.y = 440;
}
```

The reason is that without specifying the `this` keyword, you create a new variable in scope every time which is never used. Also, it stops randomly since you test for `this.isJumping` to prevent the fall to continue but never reset `this.y` variable.

Comment: Late night coding is such a bad idea for me... Thanks for showing me my error!